# How do you signup for Cloud Identity for Google Cloud Platform when you already signed up for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

At my company we want to start hosting our applications on Google Cloud Platform, so, I signed up, which asked me to create a Google Account, so, I used my business email address `pablo.fernandez@example.com` to do so. But now it looks like this is an organization-less account. When I try to sign up for Cloud Identity, so that we can have an organization and other users in the GCP account I get this error:

[image]

Does GCP require me to sign up with a temporary throway email so I can set it up correctly? At any point, how do I move forward from here?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I believe that you cannot use the same email address for a Google Account and for Google Identity. Please post an answer if you get any facts for this question as I would like to know. Perhaps Google Support will jump in with an official answer.

Comment: Do you already have G Suite setup for your example.com domain and you want to add Cloud Identity capabilities, or are you setting up the domain with Google for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Although Cloud identity is a separate service from G Suite, most probably the same rules apply when managing users: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7044710?hl=en

> Before you add users to your organization's Google domain, you should check if they have a personal Google Account with the same email address that you plan to use for their managed Google Account. Two accounts can’t share the same email address. If they do, you have 2 options:
>
> Option 1: Invite your users to transfer or rename their existing account (using a tool in the Google Admin console).
>
> Option 2: Require users to rename their existing account.
> Learn more about conflicting accounts.

I believe it is because ultimately they are all "google accounts" just that, G Suite and Cloud Identity accounts belong to an Organization.

Comment: Did this get resolved at all? I am hitting the same problem. I don't want to use Gsuite some am just registering a Google account as part of the Cloud set up process (as a Google account is required). It then rejects this email as above when I try to set up Cloud Identity.
I can't set up another Google account as I only have the one email (which needs to be confirmed during registration)